# iOS navigation bar functions correctly, but is wrong color

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, navigationbar, user-interaction

Here's my problem: I have a navigation bar at the top of a UINavigationController.  I have it set to disable and re-enable when certain popovers are onscreen.  One case isn't working: when a Dropbox popover comes on screen the bar disables as it should.  But when I close the popover (press cancel) the navigation bar re-enables as it should, but it stays grayed-out as long as the app is open, though it functions correctly.  It should return to blue at this point.  It does turn blue when I close other popovers.  Just the Dropbox one is giving me problems.  I don't see any kind of "Highlighted" attribute for the NavBar, and I'm switching the UserInteractionEnabled attribute correctly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code at the cancel action of popover.

You can use this one for ios7

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

This one for the ios6

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
// This is for iOS 7.0 or more than that.

   if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
} else {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}

 //  For text alignments 

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
      UITextAttributeTextColor,
      [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0],
      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],
      UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0],//[UIFont fontWithName:@"DynoBold" size:20.0],
      UITextAttributeFont,
      nil]];
```

Comment: This changes the tint of the entire bar.  Sorry for not being clear, but I don't want the bar to change color, just the text / icons on the buttons.

Comment: @leksah255 apply navigation bar appearence. Edited my answer please check it.